# Naming a file with a function suffix in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, filenames, suffix

I am trying to save multiple png files of circles with different colours in MATLAB. I wish to have multiple files with the name:

```
RINGS_Base_<n><colorname>
```

`n` being the number of different files displayed and `colorname` being the name of the colour of the circle.

Since the circles have an RGB colour, I transformed each RGB colour into the actual name of the color by using the function translatecolor.

Can I call that function when I am naming each one of my files? If not, how can I name all of the files with their respective colours?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Here is my code:

```
RGB = [1 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 1; 1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1];

%
%RIGNSGenerator_FilledCircle1
%
n=1;
for col1 = transpose(RGB)
    FilledCircle1(2,2,5,300,transpose(col1)) %function []=FilledCircle1(x0,y0,Radius,N,col1)
    print (strcat ('/Users/Stimuli_Rings/RINGS_Circle_', num2str(n),translatecolor(col1), '.png'), '-dpng') %strcat is to combining strings together
n=n+1;
end 




function out=translatecolor(in) % translates the RGB colour into the actual name of the color
switch(in)
    case [1 1 0], out='yellow';
    case [1 0 1], out='pink';
    case [0 1 1], out='cyan';
    case [1 0 0], out='red'; 
    case [0 1 0], out='green';
    case [0 0 1], out='blue';
        return;
end
end
```

Comment: Um... yes? Is there an actual problem here? It looks like you're already doing things (at least mostly) right...

Comment: I have the following error that I am having trouble to understand @tmpearce :>> RIGNSGenerator
SWITCH expression must be a scalar or character vector constant.

Error in RIGNSGenerator>translatecolor (line 18)
switch(in)

Error in RIGNSGenerator (line 12)
    print (strcat ('/Users/Stimuli_Rings/RINGS_Circle_', num2str(n),translatecolor(col1), '.png'), '-dpng')
    %strcat is to combining strings together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with the `translatecolor` function because the `case` statements of the `switch` statement cannot be arrays of numbers. Rather than using a `switch` statement, you could just use a sort of lookup table which relies upon having each value in a separate row and the corresponding strings in a cell array. You can then use `ismember` (with the `'rows'` option) to figure out which value corresponds to the input and then use the result to index into the array of color names.

```
values = [1 1 0;
          1 0 1;
          0 1 1;
          1 0 0;
          0 1 0;
          0 0 1];

colors = {'yellow', 'pink', 'cyan', 'red', 'green', 'blue'};

out = colors{ismember(values, in(:).', 'rows')};
```

Comment: I keep having the following error and I don't know how to address it: Error using ismember>ismemberR2012a (line 182)
Inputs A and B must be matrices with the same number of columns in the 'rows' case.

Error in ismember (line 116)
            lia = ismemberR2012a(A,B,logical(flaginds(1)));

Comment: @Mraquel Ah I see now, `in` was a column vector in your data. I've updated the code to force `in` to be a row vector, allowing the appropriate comparison.

Comment: Thank you so much @Suever !